# For Loop Return All

Tags: json, loops, for-loop, pandas, iterable

I have a Pandas data frame with json strings per row. I would like to run a for loop to json_normalize each row and bring the data back to another data frame so I can access certain key_value pairs.

My function looks like:

```
for line in df:
        json_normalize(line)
```

This prints the data that I want, but I would like to get it into an object so I can read it as a data frame and perform operations on it.
The data is as such:

```
3     [{u'from': {u'name': u'Aaron Roth', u'id': u'1...
5     [{u'from': {u'name': u'Elle Oh', u'id': u'1020...
6     [{u'from': {u'name': u'Chris Magorian', u'id':...
7     [{u'from': {u'name': u'Jimmy George', u'id': u...
8     [{u'from': {u'name': u'A'raelle Flynn-Bolden',...
12    [{u'from': {u'name': u'Aaron Roth', u'id': u'1...
13    [{u'from': {u'name': u'A'raelle Flynn-Bolden',...
16    [{u'from': {u'name': u'Matthew Emery', u'id': ...
17    [{u'from': {u'name': u'Elle Oh', u'id': u'1020...
18    [{u'from': {u'name': u'Gyasi Silas', u'id': u'...
19    [{u'from': {u'name': u'Alice Magorian', u'id':...
23    [{u'from': {u'name': u'Jonathan Jayasinghe', u...
24    [{u'from': {u'name': u'Aaron Roth', u'id': u'1...
```

Comment: I think you need a further step to flatten the JSON structure so that there is no nested/embedded documents. After that, you can just use `pandas.read_json(orient=records)` to read data into dataframe.

Comment: How would I flatten the json again? My for loop is trying to flatten it? What would you do to flatten it? I use json_normalize in an object before reading it into a data frame/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the `map` method on your json-text column to apply a `lambda` function which will parse the json using `json.loads` then return the field that you want.

```
import json

name = df.json_text.map(lambda s: json.loads(s)['from']['name'])
id = df.json_text.map(lambda s: json.loads(s)['from']['id'])

flattened = pd.DataFrame({'name':name, 'id',id})
```

Alternatively if you want to bring in all the "from" fields at once (and if there's no further nesting in this field) you could simply call

```
flattened = pd.DataFrame(name = df.json_text.map(lambda s: json.loads(s)['from']['name'])
```

Comment: that returns an error: TypeError: expected string or buffer. What should I do to pass the Series into a Str that can be read by json.loads? Or should I just pass the json_normalize function?